# Change schema protocol to http:// in WebView Android

Tags: javascript, android, http, webview, protocols

I have a WebView in my Android App, I extract with the library jsoup a "div" from an html page. In this "div", I have some javascript script that execute, but the problem is the url of the script :

```
'//' + disqus_shortname + '.' + 'disqus.com' + '/embed.js?pname=wordpress&pver=2.74
```

I don't have any protocol before the "//", so the script doesn't load, I want to add the "http" protocol before the url of the script. Any ideas?

Thank you everybody,

PS : it's my first Post :)

Answer (score 0):

Use the [WebView.loadDataWithBaseURL()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html#loadDataWithBaseURL(java.lang.String,java.lang.String,java.lang.String,java.lang.String,java.lang.String)) function to specify a base URL. The "//" is, in fact, valid and means to "use the same protocol as the base URL but with the given domain." By using "loadDataWithBaseURL" instead of the other load methods, the WebView should be able to resolve this with the base URL you specify.

Comment: Thank you for your quick answer.In fact, I've already tried this function, but I don't know what I have to put in baseUrl. There is my function loadDataWithBaseURL() :

webDisqus.loadDataWithBaseURL("http:", result, "text/html", "UTF-8", null);

Comment: It depends on what page "result" represents. If there is an online representation of result, you should use the URL for that.

Answer (score 0):

Find the solution to integrate Disqus in WebView Android :

```
return "<html><head></head><body><div id='disqus_thread'></div></body>"
            + "<script type='text/javascript'>"
            + "var disqus_identifier = '"
            + idPost
            + "';"
            + "var disqus_shortname = '"
            + shortName
            + "';"
            + " (function() { var dsq = document.createElement('script'); dsq.type = 'text/javascript'; dsq.async = true;"
            + "dsq.src = 'http://' + disqus_shortname + '.disqus.com/embed.js';"
            + "(document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0] || document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0]).appendChild(dsq); })();"
            + "</script>";
```

Hope that could be helpful :)